# Get GMT Offset from 'gmt_offset' option in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, time, timezone, gmt

I'm not perfect in PHP, I'm trying to show user's current timezone in wordpress site.
User selected GMT Timezone is: UTC+5.30
but `get_option('gmt_offset')`
returns '5.5'

How to get this '5.5' GMT offset as 'UTC+5.30' ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did:

```
$min    = 60 * get_option('gmt_offset');
$sign   = $min < 0 ? "-" : "+";
$absmin = abs($min);
$tz     = sprintf("UTC%s%02d:%02d", $sign, $absmin/60, $absmin%60);
```